# pinvoke get data from struct in c

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I am using `pinvoke` in a project I am building.
I need to get data from a function in C, the function gets pointer to a struct.
In my c# I did a class with the appropriate attribute(layountkind.sequntial).
Before the function I do:

```
mystruct str=new mystruct();
str.Data=new byte[14];
func(str);
```

I fill the struct in the function but when it exit the function the instance of the class doesn't have the values i filled in c,i check the content of the pointer before i exit the c function and it has the right values.
Below is the prototype of the function:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
void func([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] mystruct str);
```

My struct in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class mystruct
{
    public ushort familiy;
    [MatshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst=14)]
    public byte [] data;
}
```

function and struct in C:

```
struct sockaddr{
 unsigned short familiy;
 char data [14];
};
    void func(struct sockaddr *info)
{
int i;
char buffer[100]
recvfrom(sockfd,buffer,0,info,&i);//assume i have a global varible sockfd and it is an open socket
}
```

How can i fix my problem?

Comment: Without showing what is the functions signatures in C, and the actual struct (in C, not C#), there is no way to fix your problem.

Comment: @ShlomiBorovitz i edited the Q and included what you asked

Comment: It would really help if you posted the real code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i edited the Q to contain the real code

Comment: It is still not the real code. You missed `static extern`. And `Data` and `data` don't match. And now you've lost the C struct declaration. And `familiy` is surely `family`. The previous revision was better. Which I answered. I don't think it's fair to ask a new question by way of an edit to the original question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it is the real code but i have in on a pc that isn't connected to the internet so i copied in manually so that is why i have some error and typos in it but it still doesn't change the question btw the struct in c is sockaddr struct that is defined in winsock and other headers of microsoft

Comment: I can imagine how it happened. However, please understand that we've been answering questions like this for a long time and have a lot of experience. When there are typos, that often leads to us giving answers that resolve problems that are only in the typos. It's really important to be very accurate when asking so that we can focus on the crucial details with confidence in their accuracy. Anyway, I'm sure I answered the question that you asked. And the latest edit actually makes the question worse because it removed the C struct definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The p/invoke declaration is incorrect. The default marshalling is `In` only. But you need `Out` marshalling. Otherwise the marshaller won't attempt to marshal the data set by the unmanaged function back to the managed class.

So you can fix the problem by declaring the function like this:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void func([Out] mystruct str);
```

---

Personally I think that it would be more idiomatic to use a C# struct. I'd declare it like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct mystruct
{
    public ushort family;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=14)]
    public byte[] data;
}
```

And then the function becomes:

```
[DllImport(dllname, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void func(out mystruct str);
```

And the call is simply:

```
mystruct str;
func(out str);
```

Comment: thank you that worked but now after it exit the function it says that an executing engine exception was thrown and wasn't handle why is that?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't posted your real code. There are lots of errors in the code you posted. So perhaps the real code is doing something that we cannot see.

Comment: OK, but I think I answered the question that you asked (you even accepted my answer), and it seems that you now have a new and different question. The original question was a quite simple marshalling issue. The new question is more involved.

Comment: the question isn't changed before the executingengine exception(after i tried your solution) i had the problem i described in the q that the data i filled in info wasn't there when i exit the c function

Comment: *I fill the struct in the function but when it exit the function the instance of the class doesn't have the values i filled in c,i check the content of the pointer before i exit the c function and it has the right values.* That's the quote from your question. Adding `[Out]` resolves that.

Comment: your solution worked i accidentally tried ref instead of [Out] now i changed it and it worked thank you very much

Comment: An earlier edit to my answer erroneously contained `ref` because I had not spotted that you used `class`. Personally I would declare the struct as a struct in C# and use `out` to marshal it. I've updated the answer to demonstrate what I mean.